# Hacer un INSERT INTO usando un SELECT que contenga un WHERE entre tablas DBISAM

Tags: sql, select, insert, where

Buenas tengo que insert usando un select pero la tabla ya contiene datos que ya se habian insertado de manera manual, la cosa es que necesito comparar que inserte los datos que no existan ya en la tabla para evitar un error de llave primaria, ademas de que el campo PRD_REFERENCIA no este vacio ya que en la tabla que estoy haciendo el INSERT esa es la llave primaria, podria incluirle condiciones entre las dos tablas en el where?, aqui dejo el query:

```
INSERT INTO TCodigoAlterno AS T1
(CALT_CODE,CALT_PRODUCTO)
SELECT PRD_REFERENCIA,PRD_CODIGO
FROM TInventario AS T2
WHERE T2.PRD_REFERENCIA <> T1.CALT_CODE
```

Comment: el campo del PK es auto incremental? no?

Comment: El problema es que `TCodigoAlterno` tendría que ser parte del `SELECT` y no lo es. De todos modos, convendría definir quizá restricciones de integridad referencial, y/o programar algún `TRIGGER` o función que mantenga la integridad de los datos.

Comment: ¿Y lo que has hecho no te funciona? ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: Lo que hice no me funcionó, así que opte por hacer la carga en un archivo y cargar manualmente lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es seleccionar aquellas filas dónde `PRD_REFERENCIA` no existan en `TCodigoAlterno.CALT_CODE`, para esto un `NOT IN` y una subconsulta.

```
SELECT PRD_REFERENCIA, PRD_CODIGO
       FROM TInventario AS T2
       WHERE T2.PRD_REFERENCIA NOT IN (SELECT T1.CALT_CODE
                                              FROM TCodigoAlterno T1)
```